# Applying *:first-child +html in same CSS file with different attributes

Tags: css

I have one common CSS file and two pages are referring to it.

One page which is referring to this common CSS requires below CSS,

```
*:first-child + html .rich-tabpanel {
   margin-left:-13px;        // Note : Its 13px here
}
```

The other page which is referring to this common CSS requires below CSS,

```
*:first-child + html .rich-tabpanel {
   margin-left: 0px;         //Note : Its 0px here 
}
```

HTML code is below,

```
<table class="rich-tabpanel">
```

I have this problem only in IE7 where its not taking below code (I don't know why),

```
.ie7 .rich-tabpanel {
   margin-left: 13px; //OR 0px depending on the page
}
```

So, I removed above code and went with only `*:first-child + html .rich-tabpanel` code

How can I have two different `margin-left` attributes in the same common CSS file for `rich-tabpanel` attribute?

Comment: If you're already using `*:first-child + html` why do you need the `.ie7` class? Your question is very confusing.

Comment: Don't think IE7 does negative margins.

Comment: @Torr3nt: It does to *some* extent but I can't tell if it will exhibit buggy behavior here.

Comment: try adding * before margin-left: 0px; : *margin-left: 0px;

Comment: @BoltClock I initially tried with `.ie7 .rich-tabpanel`. Since, it didn't work, I removed this, and went with `*:first-child +html .rich-tabpanel`. Sorry for the confusion. Hope am clear

Comment: @Ladineko I didn't understand how it will help

Comment: `*:first-child +html .rich-tabpanel` makes no sense to me. Could you explain why you use it that way?

Comment: @Sotiris Its kind of a hack for ie7. More info [here](http://www.webmasterworld.com/css/3620063.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the moment `*:first-child +html .rich-tabpanel` is a hack, it's [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) is unknown. `.ie7 .rich-tabpanel` has specificty 0020, so the hack probably has a specifity above it. Changing the selector `.ie7 .rich-tabpanel` to `html .ie7 .rich-tabpanel` which changes the specifity then the rule is applied. I don't gurantee that is a specificity issue, but changing the selector, in any case, works.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/xWX2R/1/

In any case, I suggest you to use [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) than hacks for internet explorer.

Answer (score 0):

First, I am confused why you are applying this CSS style:

```
*:first-child +html .rich-tabpanel{
    margin-left:-13px;        // Note : Its 13px here
}
```

Specifically, what does `*:first-child +html .rich .rich-tabpanel1` even mean?

When I read that it says 'select all elements, the select the first child followed by the adjacent tag  and select .rich-tabpanel1. There is surely a better way to do this:

```
.rich-tabpanel1 { 
  //code 
}
```

There is nothing wrong with your code. One page can reference the first code block while the scond one can reference the other code block. HOWEVER this code:

```
.ie7 .rich-tabpanel {
   margin-left: 13px; //OR 0px depending on the page
}
```

Does not work unless you specifically add `.ie7` class in your html. Are you using server-side scripting to add that class into the html markup? Purposes a better way to do this is the following:

```
<!--[if IE]>
  <style type="text/css">@import url("ie.css");</style>
<![endif]-->
```

If its an IE browser, this CSS file will be fetched and used to override css properties. This gives you a lot more control over your styling.

Comment: `*:first-child + html` is a selector hack that works for IE7 because it places `html` as an adjacent sibling to some mysterious other element.